# How to pause an effect's concatMap processing, but don't cancel the complete queue?

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I'm using NGRX and Effects for basic stuff in an app. The app does bluetooth le communication and refreshes/writes various parameters constantly.
However sometimes it's necessary to pause this refreshing.

I'm having trouble with pausing the execution of an NGRX Effect which uses concatMap to queue actions into a serial queue. The queued actions should still be processed after some sort "continue" signal has been given or when the bluetoothService.paused property becomes false again. There can be many ReadFromDevice actions queued in the concatMap.

The bluetooth service has a boolean property this.bluetoothService.pauseCommunication, however I don't know how to integrate that into the Effect. I have tried various (probably stupid) things but failed so far. Unfortunately I currently can not change the bluetoothService code.

I know I can cancel the complete concatMap by throwing an error, but that's not what I need. I just need to pause the processing until the boolean flag becomes false.

This is a simplified example Effect I'm using

```js
@Effect()
  readParameterFromDevice$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<ReadFromDevice>(CommunicationActionTypes.ReadFromDevice),
    map(action => action.payload),
    concatMap(async request => {
        try {
          const result = await this.bluetoothService.readFromDevice(
            request
          );
          return new ReadSuccess({
             result
          });
        } catch (error) {
          return new ReadError({
             result
          });
        }
    })
  );
```

Would be great if anybody could point me into the right direction.

Comment: https://medium.com/js-in-action/rxjs-pause-and-resume-mighty-switchmap-41d0d1fe1113

Comment: Thank you! However if I'm not mistaken this solves a different problem. I think this approach could prevent actions from reaching my readParameterFromDevice$ effect, but it wouldn't pause the actions that have already been queued by the concatMap, or would it?

Comment: Where do you get the boolean flag that controls whether you want to process another item from the queue?

Comment: In the example above, the boolean flag would be available on this.bluetoothService.paused

Comment: It would be easier if `this.bluetoothService.paused` was an Observable.

Comment: Maybe I can request that change. Do you know how it would work with an observable?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the `buffer` operator.

> Buffers the source Observable values until closingNotifier emits.

See the [docs](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/buffer).

```
import { fromEvent, interval } from 'rxjs';
import { buffer } from 'rxjs/operators';

const clicks = fromEvent(document, 'click');
const interval = interval(1000);
const buffered = interval.pipe(buffer(clicks));
buffered.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Or the `bufferToggle` operator.

> Buffers the source Observable values starting from an emission from openings and ending when the output of closingSelector emits.

See the [docs](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/bufferToggle)

```
import { fromEvent, interval, empty } from 'rxjs';
import { bufferToggle } from 'rxjs/operators';

const clicks = fromEvent(document, 'click');
const openings = interval(1000);
const buffered = clicks.pipe(bufferToggle(openings, i =>
  i % 2 ? interval(500) : empty()
));
buffered.subscribe(x => console.log(x));
```

Comment: I think that could be what I'm looking for. I'm not yet sure how I can integrate this into the concatMap, but I'll try :-)